# Xcode 10 - how to pin UI element library window?

Tags: layout, uistoryboard, xcode10, xcode10beta6

I'm laying out UI on a storyboard using the new, controversial library button which has been moved up.

[image]

This is driving me crazy - I want to be able to "PIN" this window to a secondary monitor so I can always see available components as opposing to having to click that button every single time I need an element. Currently it disappears, even on secondary monitor once I shift focus to the view controller on screen.

**How do I pin the UI Elements library to be able to always see it ?**

[image]

Comment: Library content has moved from the bottom of the Inspector area to an overlay window, which can be moved and resized like Spotlight search. It dismisses once items are dragged, but holding the Option key before dragging will keep the library open for an additional drag. @AlexStone

Answer (score 1):

You can press the option button in keyboard and click in the library window, it's will hold

[Picture of library windown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8vWu.png)

[image]

Comment: any explaination

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.